# @viewChild not triggering modal pop and throwing error triggerModal is not a function- Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't know why click event not firing from parent component to show bootstrap 3 modal. its throwing error like below

```
ERROR TypeError: this.target.triggerModal is not a function
```

So far what i've;

**componentPrnt**

```
@ViewChild('target') private target: modalComponent;

ngOnInit(){
this.target.triggerModal();
}

<btton #target>open modal</button>
```

**modalComponet**

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {     
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {        

  }    
    triggerModal() {
        console.log('model opened');
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }
}


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `@ViewChild` as follows:

```
  @ViewChild(ModalComponent) modalC:ModalComponent; 
  parentButtonHandler(){
     this.modalC.triggerModal();
  }
```

The working demo for opening Modal of child from parent is :
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pmdzk)

Answer (score 1):

Since `target` is type of `ModalComponent`, it will be:

.html

```
<button (click)="openModal()">open modal</button>
<app-modal #target></app-modal>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild('target') private target: ModalComponent;

openModal(){
  this.target.triggerModal();
}
```

Comment: getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'triggerModal' of undefined`

Comment: What is the selector of `ModalComponent `?

Comment: `app-alert-modal` .  i need to change like this `<app-alert-modall #target></app-alert-modal>` ?

Comment: can you pls create stackblitz for this? im still getting console error even after changed with proper selector.!

Answer (score 0):

I fix my issue and the solution is here in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2wbhz) . someone may need this in future